# Ruby on rails Active record select returns always id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, activerecord

In my sample ruby apps a query like that

```
@ip = User.where("id = ?",@user[:user_id]).select('ip').first
```

returns

```
{"id":null,"ip":"127.0.0.1"}
```

And i don't want it to return id, although the id is 1, it returns is as null.

PS: it wont return id:null if i mentioned id in select like .select('id,ip')

Any help? i want just ip at return.

Comment: Is `@user` an instance of a user, or is it a hash that holds values of a user?

Comment: FYI: `where("id = ?", XXX)` should always be written as `where(id: XXX)`. Don't build query strings for simple querying of `field = value`.

Comment: @Makoto it's an instance of a user model

Comment: @meager will edit it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what `select` does. Check out the [Ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) to get a better understanding on how that method is used.

If all you're wanting to do is return the `ip` attribute from your `User` model based on finding a record with an `id`, all you need is this:

```
User.find(@user[:user_id]).ip
```

Notice that I'm using `find` and not `where`. As `id` should always be a unique value, there's no need to use a combination of `where` and `first` to get the single record you're looking for.

---

#### ALSO

Based on your example, I'm assuming that your `@user` variable is an object that you created and not a instance of your `User` model, which is why you're accessing `user_id` instead of just `id`.

However, if it *is* an instance of your `User` model, then two things to keep in mind:

1. you'll want to access `id`, not `user_id` - and you also don't need to access it via `@user[:id]`. You can just do `@user.id`.
2. you don't need to find the record at all. If you already have the `User` object that you're trying to `find`, then you can just get the `ip` from the object itself - i.e. `@user.ip`.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) instead, which will return only the value you want.

```
ip = Model.where(conditions).pluck(:ip).first
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've already got the instance of a user you care about, and the IP field isn't a join to another table, then simply pull it off of the instance.

```
@ip = @user.ip
```

There's no benefit to going back to the database for information that you already have.